# I am trying to make a login activity which proceed to another activity showing name of the user.

Tags: android

I am trying to make a login activity which proceeds to another activity by clicking. but its giving me error. here is the code....

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
     if(v.getid() == R.id.Blogin)
     {
        EditText a=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFUserName);
        String str= a.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
        i.putExtra("Username",str);
        startActivity(i);

     }
}
```

its giving me error in view and getid.. any one can help me in solving this error?

Comment: Could you post your error log?

Comment: plz post your logcat....so that we can identify where is your problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Try by this code .

First Activity:-

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
 String keyIdentifer  = null;
 i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

Second Activity :-

```
  String newString;
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(extras == null) {
       newString= null;
  } else {
     newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
  }
} else {
     newString= (String)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
```

}
complete code ..

or 
you can use shared Preference to save values of user Login.